# How to convert Object in to entity in JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to convert Object in to entity in JPA

I had a tqo table to join and which I have done and I am getting response as well. But the problem is here I am getting that as an list of array. I want this is to be list of my entity.

Here is repo

```
package com.overflow.overflow.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.overflow.overflow.models.Transictions;

@Repository
public interface TransictionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transictions, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "SELECT transiction.user_id, transiction.quantity,transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price,instrument.LTP"
            + "FROM instrument"
            + "INNER JOIN transiction"
            + "ON instrument.instrument=transiction.instrument_name")
    public List<Object[]> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
}
```

Here is my controller

```
  @GetMapping("/getTransictionsAndInstruments") 
      public List<Object[]> getTransitionInstrument(){
         return transictionrepository.getTransictionsAndInstruments(); 
      }
```

Can any body help me How to do that. I have done that for one server where I am using `findAll()` example.

```
@GetMapping("/getTransictionData")
    public List<Transictions> getAllTransiction(){
        return transictionrepository.findAll();
        //return transictionrepository.getTransictionsAndInstruments();
    }
```

Instrumet

```
package com.springboot.Ole.Model;



import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "instrument")
public class Instrument {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "instrument")
    private String instrumentName;
    
    @Column(name = "ltp")
    private float LTP;
    
    @Column(name = "exchange")
    private String exchange;
    
    @Column(name = "joCaps")
    private String joCaps;
    
    
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrument", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private List<Transictions> transiction;
     
    
    

    public Instrument(String instrumentName, float lTP, String exchange, String joCaps) {
        super();
        this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
        LTP = lTP;
        this.exchange = exchange;
        
    }
    
    public Instrument () {
        
    }
    
    
        // Getter Setter
```

Transiction

```
package com.springboot.Ole.Model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "transiction")
public class Transictions {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;
    
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long userId;
    
    @Column(name = "instrumentName")
    private String InstrumentName;
    
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;
    
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;
    
    @Column(name = "transictionDate")
    private Date transictionDate;
    
    
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      
     @JoinColumn(name = "ltp") 
      private Instrument instrument;
     
    
    public Transictions() {
    }
    
    public Transictions(Long userId, String instrumentName, int quantity, double price, Date transictionDate) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        InstrumentName = instrumentName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.transictionDate = transictionDate;
    }
    
    // Getter Setter
```

Comment: Can you add the class Transictions ? 
I think the problem came from attribute name in your request. 
Try to add an alias ( Example transiction.user_id as user_id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using native queries, you have 2 solutions, fetching data into a custom object or into an interface.

### Custom object

If you want to fetch results of a native query into a custom object which is not an entity, you can use `@SqlResultSetMapping` :

Create your custom object :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomTransiction {

    private long userId;
    private int quantity;
    private String instrumentName;
    private double price;
    private float ltp;

}
```

Define a named native query (`@NamedNativeQuery`) with the mapping information (`@SqlResultSetMapping`) so that it can fetch the results into your custom object :

```java
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "findTransictions",
        query = """
            SELECT transiction.user_id, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price, instrument.LTP
            FROM instrument
            INNER JOIN transiction
            ON instrument.instrument = transiction.instrument_name
        """,
        resultSetMapping = "transictions"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "transictions",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = CustomTransiction.class, columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "userId", type = Long.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "quantity", type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "instrucmentName", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "price", type = Double.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "ltp", type = Float.class)
                })
        }
)
```

Then use your named native query in your repository like this :

```java
@Query(name = "findTransictions", nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomTransiction> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
```

### Interface projection

A simpler way, if this is only for display purpose, is to use interface projection :

Create an interface to hold your data :

```java
public interface TransictionProjection {

    Long getUserId();
    Integer getQuantity();
    String getInstrumentName();
    Double getPrice();
    Float getLTP();

}
```

Then you can directly use it from your repository :

```java
@Query(value = """
            SELECT transiction.user_id, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price, instrument.LTP
            FROM instrument
            INNER JOIN transiction
            ON instrument.instrument = transiction.instrument_name""", nativeQuery = true)
List<TransictionProjection> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
```

Note that the column names must match the interface method names, so you may need to user aliases in your query, i.e. `SELECT transiction.user_id as userId, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name as instrumentName, ...`.

## Edit

Some explanation following the question in the comment :

Actually you have many solutions for fetching data with JPA, and it all depends on your application complexity, and what you do with the data.

### JPQL into Entity

Common way is to use JPQL (no native query) to fetch directly into a JPA entity (`@Entity` annotated).

For example : `@Query("select t from Transiction t where ...")`
It must return the entity (`Transiction`).

Problem is that it fetches all the data, inculding nested relations (depending on eager/lazy associations) and depending on your entity complexity this can be huge and performance killer. And when you look at generated SQL this can be painful... You can also faces N+1 problem. Of course you can tweek it using `fetch join`s, etc. but there is nothing magic.

However this is a must if you need to update the data later, because you must get the complete entity if you want to do a `save()`. Or you can use update queries with `@Modifying` but this is not always applicable (this is useful to avoid fetching an entire entity simply to update a status for example).

### JPQL into custom object

If you simply need some data from your entity (not all), you can use a custom model class with a constructor, so that you can call it from your SELECT query. It does not need to be an `@Entity`.

For example : `@Query("select new com.example.CustomTransiction(id, userId, price) from Transiction t where ...")`
It must return the custom object (`CustomTransiction`).

But it is still JPQL, and still JPA can generate some weird queries depending on your entity complexity. It does not prenvent N+1 problems, etc.

Also you cannot use that object to update the data, you may still need to fetch the entire entity later. This is useful for display purpose.

### Native query with interface projection

In that case you use native queries (`nativeQuery = true`), so you control your queries and SQL performance.

For example :  `@Query("select id, user_id as userId, price from transiction t where ...", nativeQuery = true)`
It must return the interface (`TransictionProjection` for example) and all fields must match.

This is the simplest and most performant solution, but this is for display purpose only as we use an interface.

You will still need to fetch the entity to update the data.

### Native query into custom object

You still use a native query, but you project the result into a custom class, not an interface. This can be done using `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping` as shwon above. And unlike the interface, you can update your object (to update UI for example). But still you will need the entity to update the data in the database.

The bad thing about native queries is that you lose some of the ORM advantages (not database agnostic anymore, you are more dependant on your database management system). To be honest even using only JPQL, you may still need some modification when switching database system (i.e. reserved words, null parameter management in PostgreSQL, etc.) so I personnaly think that this is not a big deal if you improve the performances a lot and reduce application complexity.

Comment: I have tried but getting this error. I am using interface logic by using Transiction projection "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract long com.springboot.Ole.repository.TransictionProjection.getUserId();"

Comment: `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping` o i need to write in repository or in custom object clas..

Comment: You can put the annotations in your entity class. For interface projection, the name of the columns must match the name of the interface methods, so you may need to use aliases in your query, i.e. `SELECT transiction.user_id as useriD, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name as instrumentName, transiction.Price as price, instrument.LTP as LTP FROM ...`. If some data can be null do not use primitive types in the interface, use `Long getUserId();`, `Integer getQuantity();`, etc.

Comment: I have just Changed `Integer` and It worked. thanks. My take away from this problem is "I need to creat separte class/interface to get my custom desired result if I am writing any specific query". Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, if you need to get custom result, which does not represent an entity, you need to use an interface or a custom object class. I added some more explanation about the different solutions with JPA, according to my personal experience. It's up to you to choose the right one depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Transiction Entity model.

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "instrument", referencedColumnName = "instrumentName") 
  private Instrument instrument;
```

Then this will do the job for you

```
@GetMapping("/getTransictionData")
    public List<Transictions> getAllTransiction(){
        return transictionrepository.findAll();
    }
```

Why overcomplicate things?

It is just that you want to join those to tables based on instrument name.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I am getting some error meanwhile I have updated my Instriment and transiction Model. Please have a look.

Comment: I ahve removed `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` from transiction and then clean of reposiory class. I am already using the controller method which you have written but not getting the value of ltp. 

By doing the previous code i was getting ltp in response as in array not as key value pair

Comment: Also query because it willdo join with respect to the respective instrument name.

Comment: @David check updated answer. If you modify the `@JoinColumn` correctly then JPA would be able to join those 2 entities based on instrumentName and then findAll will correctly return the instruments as well

Comment: oh ok ,  after getting that line I am getting some 'Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource' error. let me check what is that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create constructor in your entity class that you want to return and then in select section use that constructor.

```
    @Query("select new com.PACKAGE_NAME.YOUR_ENTITY_NAME(transiction.user_id, transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price,instrument.LTP) from YOUR_ENTITY_NAME transiction")
List<Your Entity Name> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
```

in your case it will look like this:

```
    @Query("select new com.springboot.Ole.Model.Transictions(transiction.user_id, transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price,instrument.LTP) from Transictions transiction")
    List<Transictions> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
```