How to use a nativeQuery with Spring and Java DTOs
I want to query a Select with multiple joins and assign it to an DTO.
As there are coming multiple fields from multiple joined tables, i tried using an DTO instead of an entity. I know i can create a view of the query and map it to an entity but there also should be a way to use native queries with DTOs, right?
I tried following Code inside a Java Spring 17 environment:
My Repo:
package felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories;

import felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository {
    @Query(value = "SELECT a.Ident AS Ident, " +
            "RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ProdDataMgmt.dbo.RTF2Text(CONCAT(a.LangText, 'X')), '}', ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(9), ''))) as Langtext, " +
            "a.KurzText AS KurzText, a.BestEinh AS BestEinh " +
            "FROM [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[ArtGrp] ag " +
            "LEFT JOIN [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[ArtGrpZu] agz ON agz.ArtGrpIndex = ag.Ident " +
            "LEFT JOIN [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[Artikel] a ON a.Ident = agz.ArtikelIndex " +
            "WHERE ag.Ident = :artGrpIdent",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<ArtikelDTO> findArtikelByArtGrpIdent(@Param("artGrpIdent") Long artGrpIdent);
}

My DTO 'Artikel':
package felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model;

public class ArtikelDTO {
    private Long Ident;
    private String KurzText;
    private String LangText;
    private String BestEinh;

    // Constructor, Getters, and Setters
    public ArtikelDTO(Long Ident, String KurzText, String LangText, String BestEinh) {
        this.Ident = Ident;
        this.KurzText = KurzText;
        this.LangText = LangText;
        this.BestEinh = BestEinh;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return new String("ident:" + Ident + ",kurzText:" + KurzText + ",langText:" + LangText + ",bestEinh:" + BestEinh);
    }
//Getters, setters...

And now the Service for the exectuion:
@Service
public class ArtikelArtikelgruppenservice {

    @Autowired
    private ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository artikelArtikelgruppenRepository;

    public List<ArtikelDTO> getArtikelByArtGrpIdent(Long artGrpIdent) {
        return artikelArtikelgruppenRepository.findArtikelByArtGrpIdent(artGrpIdent);
    }
}


My error code:
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.4)

2024-09-25 10:55:05.436 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] f.w.H.HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication - Starting HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication using Java 21 with PID 15688 (D:\Intellij_Projects\HELMIxInternBestellService\target\classes started by Stefan Kulig in D:\Intellij_Projects\HELMIxInternBestellService)
2024-09-25 10:55:05.439 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] f.w.H.HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication - The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-09-25 10:55:06.388 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-09-25 10:55:06.388 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.30]
2024-09-25 10:55:06.445 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-09-25 10:55:06.587 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-09-25 10:55:06.828 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 65e85686-ac3a-48e0-a64b-e2e47fd7606a
2024-09-25 10:55:06.830 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-09-25 10:55:06.866 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-09-25 10:55:06.911 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.6.1.Final
2024-09-25 10:55:06.941 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.h.c.i.RegionFactoryInitiator - HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-09-25 10:55:07.264 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001005: Database info:
    Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
    Database driver: undefined/unknown
    Database version: 12.0
    Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
    Isolation level: undefined/unknown
    Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
    Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown
2024-09-25 10:55:07.519 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-09-25 10:55:07.566 [main] [WARN ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenservice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2024-09-25 10:55:07.568 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-09-25 10:55:07.569 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-09-25 10:55:07.571 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-09-25 10:55:07.594 [main] [ERROR] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field artikelArtikelgruppenRepository in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.service.ArtikelArtikelgruppenservice required a bean of type 'felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:7108', transport: 'socket'

I dont understand the Action of defining a bean to it since thats not possible and it has the @Repository anyways
Furthermore:

i checked my DTO and repo for case sensitivity
my SpringApplication has @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories") and the repo is in the right place
(I already thought about creating a view and making an enitity but i do not want to create a view for it if possible)

As far as i know, it has to do something with the @Autowired of ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository, because directly at starting my program it gets the error. And when i comment the @Autowired out it doesnt show the error.
What am i doing wrong my Interface 'ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository'?
Or is my approach for using native queries and DTOs completely wrong?
Edit: tried adding "extends CrudRepository<ArtikelDTO, Long>" to my Repository "ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository", now the error i get is as following:
2024-09-25 12:45:34.021 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-09-25 12:45:34.189 [main] [WARN ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenservice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository': Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
2024-09-25 12:45:34.191 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-09-25 12:45:34.193 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-09-25 12:45:34.194 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-09-25 12:45:34.218 [main] [ERROR] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenservice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository': Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication.main(HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:1)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:10576', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

Edit2: Tried the solution with @NamedNativeQuery from @Yann39:
my ArtikelDTO
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "findTransictions",
        query = """
                SELECT a.Ident AS Ident,\s
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ProdDataMgmt.dbo.RTF2Text(CONCAT(a.LangText, 'X')), '}', ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(9), ''))) AS LangText,
                       a.KurzText AS KurzText,\s
                       a.BestEinh AS BestEinh
                FROM [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[ArtGrp] ag
                LEFT JOIN [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[ArtGrpZu] agz ON agz.ArtGrpIndex = ag.Ident
                LEFT JOIN [FenOfficeNG].[dbo].[Artikel] a ON a.Ident = agz.ArtikelIndex
                WHERE ag.Ident = :artGrpIdent
                  """,
        resultSetMapping = "findArtikel"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "findArtikel",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ArtikelDTO.class, columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "Ident", type = Long.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "KurzText", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "LangText", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "BestEinh", type = String.class),
                })
        }
)
public class ArtikelDTO {
    private Long Ident;
    private String KurzText;
    private String LangText;
    private String BestEinh;

    public String toString() {
        return new String("ident:" + Ident + ",kurzText:" + KurzText + ",langText:" + LangText + ",bestEinh:" + BestEinh);
    }

}

Repository:
@Repository
public interface ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository extends JpaRepository<ArtikelDTO, Long> {
    @Query(name = "findArtikel", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ArtikelDTO> findArtikelByArtGrpIdent(@Param("artGrpIdent") Long artGrpIdent);
}

following error occured:
2024-09-25 15:32:59.645 [main] [WARN ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenservice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository': Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
2024-09-25 15:32:59.646 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-09-25 15:32:59.648 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-09-25 15:32:59.650 [main] [INFO ] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-09-25 15:32:59.672 [main] [ERROR] [HELMIxInternBestellService] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenservice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository': Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication.main(HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artikelArtikelgruppenRepository' defined in felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.repositories.ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HelmIxInternBestellServiceApplication: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class felbermayer.webapp.HELMIxInternBestellService.model.ArtikelDTO
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:1)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:17146', transport: 'socket'



What am i doing wrong my Interface 'ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository'?
ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository  needs to extend one of the Spring Data repository types:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/package-summary.html

Thank you. Tried that already in the past, but it didnt solve the problem yet, could you have a look at the error? im not quite sure what to try next. - see in the edit the new error

You cannot fetch a native query into a custom DTO class, you either have to use an interface, or use @NamedNativeQuery, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224481/1274485

You n eed to extend a Spring Data repository else it won't be detected. Which might lead to a different error but that is something to solve next. CrudRepository<ArtikelDTO, Long> is wrong as you should reference the JPA entity not the dto you are creating.

@Yann39 thank you for the link. Does this mean i create my DTO and add the @NamedNativeQuery inside this DTO and manually map the values of the future result to my DTO with @SqlResultSetMapping?

@Yann39 i added the changes in "Edit2" - should the correct implementation look like this?

You have been given the answer twice above. Extend a Spring Data repository and do it in a valid way.  This is not valid public interface ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository extends JpaRepository<ArtikelDTO, Long>. Assuming your entity is named Artikel then it should be  public interface ArtikelArtikelgruppenRepository extends JpaRepository<Artikel, Long>` i.e. a respository takes the entity type as a generic parameter. ArtikelDTO is not an entity

@Stefan if you want to go with @SqlResultSetMapping yes your edit is correct, except that you have to use the name of the NamedNativeQuery in your repository (findTransictions as you kept it), not the name of the SqlResultSetMapping (findArtikel). So if you use @Query(name = "findTransictions", nativeQuery = true) it should work. Of course you can give it a more appropriate name. Also fix your extends JpaRepository... as other answers suggest.
